# Problema ao exibir popup ao enviar formulários

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

Desenvolvi um formulário, quando o usuário clicar no botão enviar aparece um GIF e depois tem que aparecer um modal falando que as informações foram enviadas até ai tudo bem o GIF funciona normal porem quando o formulário e submetido o GIF some e o POPUPnão aparece gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo errado segue meu código Javascript:

```
 $("#submit-btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $('form').serializeArray();

    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-warranty')) {
        var inputRangeValue = $('.final-value').first().text();
        var specialty = {name: 'specialty', value: $('#specialty').val()};
        var value = {name: 'value', value: inputRangeValue + '000'};
        data.push(specialty);
        data.push(value);
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-indenizometro')) {
        var question_1 = $('input[name=question_1]:checked').val();
        var question_2 = $('input[name=question_2]:checked').val();
        var question_3 = $('input[name=question_3]:checked').val();
        //var reason =  {name: 'reason', value: sessionStorage.tipo };
        var monthly = {name: 'monthly', value: $('#monthly-value').text()};

        data.push(question_1);
        data.push(question_2);
        data.push(question_3);
        data.push(monthly);
        //data.push(reason);
    }

    var product = {name: 'product', value: window.location.pathname};
    data.push(product);
    $('.loaderImage').show();
    //Ajax post data to server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/request',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
            $('#modal-success').modal('show');
            $('form')[0].reset();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

OBS: só lembrando que o modal que to usando é do boostrap

Comment: O que você quer fazer com um modal dentro de uma *callback* do JQuery?

Comment: tipo quando eu clico em enviar aparece um gif no botão porque demora muito para enviar o form ai implementei essa gif mais ai quando o form e enviado ela some ai o popup teria que aparecer mais ele não aparece

Comment: Abre o console do Chrome e vê se tem um erro qualquer. Vê [**essa simulação**](https://jsfiddle.net/TonnyMontana/r2ch975y/) que eu fiz. Aparentemente seu código não possui nada errado. Troca `.click()` por `.on( "click", function () { ... });`

Comment: Eu ainda vou acrescentar o seguinte: usando *modals* é uma péssima ideia para notificação. Eles são intrusivos e atrapalham, além disso é um click a mais pra mim, o usuário. Use algo como [**NotifyJS**](https://notifyjs.com/), bem mais elegante e é só uma notificação.

Answer (score 1):

Sua logica não está errada, mas creio que isto seja um problema de carregamento onde o id `$('#modal-success')` não foi reconhecido.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(#botao).click( function(){
            $('.loaderImage').show();
            //Ajax post data to server
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/request',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.loaderImage').hide();
                $('#modal-success').modal('show');
                $('form')[0].reset();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O evento `ready` dispara o carregamento do código JavaScript depois que todo o documento HTML for carregado, evitando assim que algum elemento não seja reconhecido.
Fiz alguns teste em casa com base no seu exemplo e funcionou

Comment: amigo vou atualizar meu códifo para ver ser toda a chave como está

Comment: ta la atualizei o js

Comment: Este código está em arquivo separado certo?

Comment: isso mesmo esta em um arquivo chamado app.js

Comment: Então agora pegue todo o código deste arquivo e coloque dentro do $(document).ready( function(){ ...todo o seu codigo   });

Comment: Se ele tiver colocado `app.js` no final do documento, antes de fechar `body` (`</body>`), isso não é necessário.